# How Do You Change Parent Component' State From Child Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**What I'm Trying To Do**

In my first component, I get items that's status is 2 and make them into checkbox.

In my second component, I change items's status to 3.

Im third component, after changing status in the second component, modal opens.

When Modal closes, navigation goes back to the first component.

**The Problem** is that items I changed their status are still in the first component.

Their status is 3, so they shouldn't be in the first component.

In this case, how do you solve this?

it looks like, componentDidUpdate doesn't work here.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices.

**Current Code**

*first component*

```js
export default class fist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      checkedItems: [],
    };
  }

  onUpdate = (item) => {
    this.setState((previous) => {
      const { checkedItems } = previous;
      const index = checkedItems.indexOf(item);
      if (index === -1) {
        checkedItems.push(item);
      } else {
        checkedItems.splice(index, 1);
      }
      return { checkedItems };
    });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const items = db.itemsCollection
      .where('status', '==', 2)
      .get();
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  render() {
    const { items, checkedItems } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <View style={styles.list_asset}>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <View style={styles.article_asset} key={item.id}>
              <Text style={styles.phrase}>{item.name}</Text>
              <View style={styles.area_price}>
                <CheckBox
                  style={styles.check}
                  checked={!!checkedItems.find((obj) => obj == item)}
                  onPress={() => this.onUpdate(item)}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

*second component*

```js
updateItemsStatus = (id) => {
    this.itemsCollection.doc(id).update({
      status: 3,
      updated_at: new Date(),
    });
    return true;
  }
```

*third component*

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('first component')}}
>
  <Text>Close Modal</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Where is `componentDidUpdate` in your question? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example and clear details about the issue and expected behavior. In this case we need more code and a set a reproducible steps to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, your problem is that your data are not refreshed after the modal is closed.

That's because you get your data in `ComponentDidmount()` which is triggered once, and then you directly update the database.

In your second component, you can pass a method from your parent that will update your state. Here is a generic example :

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {...items};

  updateState = (newStatus) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, status:newStatus}));
    // or get data again from your db (careful about async)
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Child updateState={updateState} />
    )
  }

}

class Child  extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.updateState(3)}>Touch me daddy</TouchableOpacity>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to say. After the modal is closed, datas in first component are not refreshed. That's the problem that I'm facing.

Comment: Ok so i edited my answer to show you a way to do it

Comment: Thanks. But your code looks difficult for me. Does componentWillMount solve this?

Comment: No. I added "this.props." in the child component. It is a simple prop but instead of a commonly seen prop, here i pass a function reference